# Why does it say "undefined reference" when I add references from my bib file?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, footnotes

I have a problem with inserting references from my `.bib` file into my LaTeX document. Even though it runs when I only put in `\bibliography{name of my file}`, it cannot find the actual reference when I put `\cite{citation key}` (error: undefined reference). I made sure that the citation key is correct. Also I want the reference to appear in the footnotes. Can anyone see where I made the mistake?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charter}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Masterarbeit} 
\bibliographystyle{siam}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=25mm, left=20mm, right=30mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{12}{14.4}}
\renewcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large{14}{16.8}}
\renewcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE{18}{21.6}}
\renewcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge{20}{24}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\chapnumsize}{\LARGE}
\newcommand{\chapnumstyle}{\normalfont\mdseries}
\newcommand{\chapsize}{\huge}
\newcommand{\chapstyle}{\mdseries}
\newcommand{\secsize}{\large}
\newcommand{\secstyle}{\mdseries}

\addtokomafont{part}{\mdseries}
\addtokomafont{partnumber}{\mdseries}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\mdseries}
\addtokomafont{section}{\mdseries}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Fragebogen} 
\section{...}
I want to put a reference in a footnote \cite{Carbon2019}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the entry for `Carbon2019` in your bib file in your question.

Comment: Common issues are the lack of commas after each field for `Carbon2019`, not saving the bib file after adding the new entry or not compiling two times the tex file.

Comment: latex never loads the bib file, have you run bibtex to generate the bibliography?

Comment: Thank you for your responses! Here is the entry for the citation as generated by JabRef: @Article{Carbon2019,
  author  = {Carbon, C. C.},
  journal = {Journal of Perceptual Imaging},
  title   = {Empirical Approaches to Studying Art Experience},
  year    = {2019},
  number  = {1},
  volume  = {2},
  groups  = {Perceptual processes},
}

Comment: Since you're using the `biblatex` package, you must get rid of the `\bibliographystyle` statement. You should also replace `\bibliography{Masterarbeit} ` with `\addbibresource{Masterarbeit.bib}`.

Comment: Thanks Mico! However, it is still not working. I think that there is an issue with my bib file that I have to fix first...

Comment: You must not use `\bibliographystyle` with `biblatex`. **Remove the `\bibliographystyle{siam}`.** You probably want to use `\autocite{Carbon2019}` instead of `\cite{Carbon2019}`. After you have changed these two things, go to your document folder and delete the `.aux` and `.bbl` files. Then rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX. ...

Comment: ... If you still get unexpected results, please find and post the contents of the `.blg` file. On Windows systems the `.blg` file may be recognised as "performance monitor" file or some such, but it is just a simple text file you can open with your favourite text editor.

Comment: One last thing: It is not clear to me whether you (or maybe your editor) have run BibTeX. Your document must be compiled with LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX in order to properly generate all references. Why that is necessary is explained brilliantly in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 (so please head over there and give the answer a short read).

Comment: Thank you @moewe! I already did compile with LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX. I am actually using LuaLaTeX. Does this make any difference? I copied the contents of the .blg file generated for my main file:

Comment: This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019)
Capacity: max_strings=100000, hash_size=100000, hash_prime=85009
The top-level auxiliary file: Masterarbeit_Text.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file Masterarbeit_Text.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Masterarbeit_Text.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Masterarbeit_Text.aux
You've used 0 entries,
            0 wiz_defined-function locations,
            83 strings with 508 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 0 in all, are:

Comment: = -- 0
> -- 0
< -- 0
+ -- 0
- -- 0
* -- 0
:= -- 0
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 0
change.case$ -- 0
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 0
duplicate$ -- 0
empty$ -- 0
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 0
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 0
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 0
preamble$ -- 0
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 0
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 0
swap$ -- 0
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 0
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 0
(There were 3 error messages)

Comment: No, LuaLaTeX does not make a difference for the general procedure. You would just call LuaLaTeX, BibTeX, LuaLaTeX, LuaLaTeX (sometimes when I post a comment like this I include a note that "LaTeX" can be replaced by pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX at will). The relevant bits from your `.blg` file are ` I found no \citation commands---while reading file Masterarbeit_Text.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Masterarbeit_Text.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Masterarbeit_Text.aux`. That means that BibTeX can't find any citation info. ...

Comment: ... Does that `.blg` file come from the code shown in the question or already from the code as changed in the answer? If you removed the option `backend=bibtex,` you are switching to the default `backend=biber,` and need to run BibTeX instead of Biber in the compilation sequence. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help with getting your editor to run Biber instead of BibTeX.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is probably something wrong in the path of      `\bibliography{}` command.

In the MWE that follows, the relevant lines to the successful creation of the bibliography are:

```
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % include the path to your .bib file
```

in which I've removed the `\bibliographystyle{}` command (the `style=` option has to be used) and replaced `\bibliography` with `\addbibresource{}`.
If you do not specify any backend, compile with Biber after LaTeX.

Finally, in the text, use `\autocite{}`.

Commenting out all that is non relevant to the reproduction of your problem, this is a MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Article{Carbon2019,
        author = {Carbon, C. C.},
        journal = {Journal of Perceptual Imaging},
        title = {Empirical Approaches to Studying Art Experience},
        year = {2019},
        number = {1},
        volume = {2},
        groups = {Perceptual processes},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
% \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
% \usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{Charter}

\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% \usepackage{geometry}
% \geometry{top=25mm, left=20mm, right=30mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand\normalsize{\@setfontsize\normalsize{12}{14.4}}
% \renewcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large{14}{16.8}}
% \renewcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE{18}{21.6}}
% \renewcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge{20}{24}}
% \makeatother

% \newcommand{\chapnumsize}{\LARGE}
% \newcommand{\chapnumstyle}{\normalfont\mdseries}
% \newcommand{\chapsize}{\huge}
% \newcommand{\chapstyle}{\mdseries}
% \newcommand{\secsize}{\large}
% \newcommand{\secstyle}{\mdseries}

% \addtokomafont{part}{\mdseries}
% \addtokomafont{partnumber}{\mdseries}
% \addtokomafont{chapter}{\mdseries}
% \addtokomafont{section}{\mdseries}

% \setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Fragebogen}
\section{...}
I want to put a reference in a footnote \autocite{Carbon2019}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you look at the edit history of the answer, it was initially as you say :)

Comment: Good use of `\autocite`! But please mention explicitly that `\bibliographystyle` must not be used with `biblatex`, so **`\bibliographystyle{siam}` must be removed**. (It's commented out in your code, but it may not be clear to every reader that it is commented out because it must be removed and not just because it is irrelevant to the issue). It may also be useful to explicitly point out that you switched to `\addbibresource{<file>.bib}` from `\bibliography{<file>}` (which is a good choice, but not necessary, `\bibliography{Masterarbeit}` should work if the file exists).

Comment: thanks @moewe, earlier today I answered on the fly. I've updated the answer following your suggestions.

Comment: The `.bib` file extension **is** mandatory when `\addbibresource` is used. (Please correct the comment `the file extension is not mandatory` in the first code block.)